# Await is disposing DbContext - The ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following in an `async` method that has an instance of `dbContext` passed into it:

```
 var userIds = await GetUserIds(db);
```

With GetUserIds:

```
    private async Task<List<int>> GetUserIds(AppContext db)
    {
        var items = await db.Items.Where(s => s.IsValid).Distinct().ToListAsync(); // simplified
        return items;
    }
```

But I get:

> {"The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be
>   used for operations that require a connection."}

I can force this to run by removing `await` and `ToListAsync`, but obviously that's just a bandaid.  Why is my context getting disposed?

Comment: `await` doesn't dispose the `DbContext`. The problem is in code you haven't posted. Some IoC containers are too eager in their disposal; this could cause what you're seeing.

Comment: @StephenCleary thank you for the continued help.  I'll post up the surrounding code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the caller of your `GetUserIds` method is disposing the context before the operation completes. Are you sure you're awaiting the returned Task before disposing the context?